# Creating relationships in MongoDB using Mongoose (in Node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have tried to find any similiar issues here on Stackoverflow without any luck. I am struggling to find the proper way to create a relationship between two documents. It is a very simple case of hierarchical categories. Each category can have ONE parent and multiple children.

```
var categorySchema = Schema({
    name: String,
    parent: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' },
    children: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' }],
    order: Number
});

var Category = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema);
```

When I create a new Category I get the _id to the (if any) parent it should have. I get this _id as a String from a POST/PUT request and fetch the Category using this _id. The fetch works fine and I get the right Category as a result. But this is where I struggle, how do I use the returned result from the mongoose query to create the relationship between the new Category and its Parent?

```
var query = Category.find({'_id': parentCategoryID});
query.select('name');
query.exec(function (err, parentCategory) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("Fetched parentCategory: "+parentCategory+".. parentCategory._id: "+parentCategory._id);
        var parent = parentCategory.toObject();
        var category = new Category();
        category.name = name;
        category.parent = Schema.ObjectId(parent._id);
```

**console.log**
Fetched parentCategory: { name: 'Parent Category', _id:
5218dcd6e6887dae40000002 }.. parentCategory._id: undefined

I have tried setting the parent attribute in a multiple different ways and I cannot get it to work. Haven't had any luck finding documentation on the issue either.

Very thankful for ANY help in the matter and I hope more people can benefit from any answer to this question.

Comment: This sounds more like a job for a graph-database like Neo4j than for a document-oriented database like MongoDB.

Comment: I dont really see how you could get enough information from my question to come to that conclusion. The Category part is only a tiny part of the actual data model. Then again, I haven't done extensive research about MongoDB pros/cons, I picked MongoDB to learn something new. Thanks for your input though, never heard of Neo4j before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//problem 1: `find` returns a list of results. You just need findById
var query = Category.findById(parentCategoryID);
query.select('name');
query.exec(function (err, parentCategory) {
  //Problem 2: don't ignore errors. Handle them first and short-circuit return
    if (err) {
      console.err(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log("Fetched parentCategory: "+parentCategory+".. parentCategory._id: "+parentCategory._id);
    //problem 3: mongoose will do the right thing with your schema here
    //all you need is
    var category = new Category();
    category.name = name;
    category.parent = parentCategory;
    //and don't forget
    category.save(...callback....);
}
```

Also note if you have a schema, and you assign something that does not match the schema, mongoose will just drop the data, which is probably what was happening to you, assuming you called `category.save()` at some point.

Comment: I removed error handling and save for the sake of not bloating the key parts of my question. Obviously these are present.

You were right, the above code works. I guess I failed to test this way to assign the parentCategory after fixing my Schema.

Thank you!

Comment: Don't forget to handle parentCategory being null as well.